# sqlsrv_connect not defined, but works

Tags: php, sql-server, visual-studio-code

So I've followed a guide, to include the extensions for Microsoft Drivers (mssql), into my XAMPP php/ext folder. I can now use the functions, but in my VScode the functions is still marked with red 'not defined', How can I change this, so the red underline gets removed, and my VScode can find the functions used?

[image: Test]

**CODE**

```php
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: This is going to be an issue with VSCode not recognizing the installed libraries, not a coding issue itself or an issue with the installed PHP packages. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that program.

Comment: There is some other reason for the red underline, If I code `$x = I_Really_dont_exist();` VSCode does not undeline that in red ?? Maybe if you show us a bit more of the code. Note please post code as TEXT and not as a picture

Comment: `$x = I_Really_dont_exist();` will be underlined as red since the function doesn't exists @RiggsFolly

Comment: So my guess ( I admit its a guess ) is that you either HAVE a Extension I dont or you do NOT HAVE an Extension that I do :) :)

Comment: Well its NOT UNDERLINES in my VSCode :) And your code is also not underlined. And I dont have SQLServer on my PC or its drivers and extensions activated in my current PHP

Comment: if I hover my mouse over `sqlsrv_connect(...)` is says `undefined function ...` but the function is defined somewhere since I can use it. Can it be because the VScode looks at a wrong extension folder, the exstension is inside `xampp`? What I'm trying to get is information like this over hovering the function `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-connect?view=sql-server-ver15`

Comment: Do you have the extensions `PHP Intelliphense` or `PHP Intelisense` installed

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging for this problem, I've managed to solve it by going into extensions > PHP Intelephense > extension settings, and then

- Enviroment:Include paths (Here I add manually the paths of the sqlsrv.dll)
- Stubs (Here I manually enabled the sqlsrv extension)

[image]

Comment: The definitive solution. Thanks.